# How to get friend's birthday list using facebook api?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to get friend birthday list.

But how to find using my api I dont know.

Comment: It might help for you to go through and accept answers on some of your 23 questions...people here will be more likely to help if they know they might be able to get some rep for their effort...

Comment: What does this have to do with android?

Comment: which language? what platform? sample code? error messages? no accepted answers.. this is like a master class in how not to use SO :) might want to think through how you approach this site..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> **Note:** This is no longer possible. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28747657/1902010).

Use the OpenGraph API in whatever environment you  use to retrieve the information. The birthday is in the user information object, see docs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

Comment: I would be helpful if you kindly give a demo code to access birthday list with this api. If possible!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: you can get birthdays using graph api https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday&access_token=<your token here> be sure you have permission to your friends list and birthday or it will return null.

Answer (score 21):

Since v2.0 of the Graph API, it´s not possible to get friend birthdays anymore. You can only get the birthday of the authorized user by using the `user_birthday` permission. See the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

There is only one other possibility: If the friend authorized the App with `user_birthday`, you can get his birthday with the following call: `/friend-id?fields=birthday`

Of course you need to authorize users with `user_friends` too, in order to make this work. And you can also just store the birthday of all authorized users and don´t waste an extra API call on it.

Comment: I *think* you need `user_friends` as well.

Comment: well, you don´t get any friends without that, so i thought that would be obvious :) - but i will add it, just to be safe. it may not be obvious for everyone.

Comment: You know Facebook developers.. obvious is the furthest thing

Answer (score 20):

You can also use facebook api :

```php
$friends_birthday = $facebook->api("/me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday");
```

you must also have permission `friends_birthday` in the scope of your app

Comment: Please beware that the date is relative to the locale of the user so it might be mm/dd/yyy or dd/mm/yyyy or dd/mm or mm/dd

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, read the readme on the [project page to get started with the SDK](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/).

You'll then need to look at the [API reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and more specifically the [user profile section](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user).

After you've done all that you'll end up with a JSON object you can parse using the [org.json package](http://d.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) in the Android SDK.

Hopefully that helps you out.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use FQL to get a list of friend's birthday.

FQL would be (just replace your access token):

> "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select name, birthday_date from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())&access_token=**your_access_token**"

Comment: Note: `<error_msg>REST API is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher (12)</error_msg>`

Answer (score 6):

This is the link for Graph API Explorer

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me go the link and click on **Get Access Tocken** you can have a pop-up for **select permissions**
>   and select your access token.
>   and at the node section select the fields you want ( example select friends and as a sublink in friends select birthday) and **GET** a query by clicking on **SUBMIT** then you can have a friend's birthday and id along with yours as a Json Data.

Answer (score 0):

get the full friend list with Graph api , iterate json data array and then check for birthday=today .. that is

Answer (score 0):

you can get friend list in ios this way:

```
- (IBAction)pickFriendsClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"user_birthday",@"friends_hometown",
                        @"friends_birthday",@"friends_location",
                        nil];
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:nil];
    FBRequest *friendRequest = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=name,picture,birthday,location,updated_time,email"];
    [ friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSArray *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSMutableArray *friends= [data mutableCopy];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"updated_time"
                                                                   ascending:TRUE];
    [friends sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

    for (FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser> *friend in friends) {
        NSLog(@"%@:%@", [friend name],[friend birthday]);
    }}];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this , it require only few lines

```
FBRequest * request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/friends?   
                                          fields=id,name,birthday&limit=5000"];

[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) 
{
    if(error == nil){

         NSLog(@"%@",result); 
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

`FB.api('me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday')` doesnt work as of 09/12/2017.

Below is the debug message from graph explorer tool when i try to hit the endpoint.

```
Only friends who installed this app are returned in API v2.0 and higher. total_count in summary represents the total number of friends, including those who haven't installed the app
```

For returning just the friends list of the user, you can try hitting the below endpoint with a valid access token

```
FB.api('me/friendlists')
```

But note that you need **read_custom_friendlists**  permission from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example URL from Facebook Graph API Explorer:

```
me?fields=email,birthday,friends{birthday}
```

Android Java Code:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
  accessToken,
  new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
      // Insert your code here
    }
});
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "email,birthday,friends{birthday}");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

iOS SDK:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
    initWithGraphPath:@"/me"
           parameters:@{ @"fields": @"email,birthday,friends{birthday}",}
           HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    // Insert your code here
}];
```

Javascript SDK:

```
FB.api(
  '/me',
  'GET',
  {"fields":"email,birthday,friends{birthday}"},
  function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
  }
);
```

cURL:

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/me?fields=email%2Cbirthday%2Cfriends%7Bbirthday%7D&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

You can add more parameters inside the curly braces if you need more details. i.e {birthday, email, first_name, gender, location} and so on.