# How to get all friends name, id, birthday, location, etc.. from facebook API in android?

Tags: android, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get friend's birthday list using facebook api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393610/how-to-get-friends-birthday-list-using-facebook-api)

I want to display the list that contain information like name, id, birthday, location from facebook in android application.

I am beat successful in work though the following code I have get the friend's name and ID

```
           Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    mAccessToken = facebook.getAccessToken();

    try {

        parameters.putString("format", "json");
        parameters.putString(TOKEN, mAccessToken);

        String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends";
        String response = Util.openUrl(url, "GET", parameters);
        JSONObject obj = Util.parseJson(response);

        Log.i("json Response", obj.toString());
        JSONArray array = obj.optJSONArray("data");

        if (array != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                String name = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");

                String id = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");

                Log.i(name,id);
            }
        } 

                ............
                ............
```

but not get birthday, location, etc fields in json response. 
what is mistake?

Comment: "https://graph.facebook.com/[id]" returns only ID's and names of user. try another methods, search on facebook documentation (not recommanded) or google it. :)
P.S. I've worked a lot to do this... i cannot write the code in here...

Comment: Hi! I've used your code to retrieve from facebook user's friend list but I get the following error- com.facebook.android.FacebookError: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.Could u please help me to fix this!

Comment: @milind : Can you give me complete demo ?

Answer (score 9):

Use the FQL language to get very quickly all the information you want:

```
$this->api->api(array('method'=>'fql.query','query'=>"SELECT uid,name,first_name,middle_name,last_name,pic_square,hometown_location,current_location,profile_url,email,website FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())"));
```

For a list of all the tables with their corresponding column names I refer to: [Facebook FQL Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)

Answer (score 6):

When I wanted to get a list of my friends, and filter on just their name and website, this worked for me: https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=name,website&access_token=someCrazyLongRandomlyGeneratedString

Seems like you should be doing that, and you would just replace 'name,website' with 'name,id,birthday,location' or whatever you'd like to get in the response from the list of fields contained in the User object: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/. I believe id is automatically included with the response, so you don't have to actually include it in the request.

Answer (score 5):

The Facebook API [says](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/friendlist/) `FriendList` only contains an `id` and `name` for each friend.

I've not used the Facebook API, but I *think* you'll then need to query `https://graph.facebook.com/[id]` for each user, inserting their id as appropriate, to return all available information and then parse each user's JSON response separately ([their docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) aren't particularly clear).

Comment: Hi Thanks for response. bye using the above URl i get the json response for friends detail that are mansion first name, last name, locate and link. but unable to get address and birthdate

Comment: That may be due to the privacy policy that Facebook enforces. Some people choose not to give such information away, or make it only available to certain Facebook apps.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving name, id, birthday and location of a user's friends can be done with this FQL call:

```
SELECT uid,name, birthday_date, hometown_location 
FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

On Android, using the Facebook Android SDK, this can be implemented as:

```
String query = "SELECT uid,name,birthday_date, hometown_location FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())"
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("method", "fql.query");
params.putString("query", query);
mAsyncFacebookRunner.request(null, params, new FQLRequestListener())
```

where FQLRequestListener extends RequestListener.

You need these permissions:

```
friends_birthday
friends_hometown
```

Answer (score 0):

Your already close to it, use this in the url, be sure you have permission for friends_birthday and friends_location

```
String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday,location";
```