# Retrieving friends info using Facebook API

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get all friends name, id, birthday, location, etc.. from facebook API in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645595/how-to-get-all-friends-name-id-birthday-location-etc-from-facebook-api-in)

I am trying to set up a Facebook application where I have to compare the information of the user with his friends. I do not know how to retrieve the friends information such as birthday, hometown, etc. I tried using

```
$facebook->api('/Friend_ID')
```

but this is not working. However I have already set up the extended permissions. Only to retrieve the information, I am unable to do this.. Can you please guide me?

Comment: What are the current permissions?

Comment: the permissions are as follows: friends_birthday, friends_location, friends_work_history, friends_education_history, friends_activities, friends_hometown, friends_interests, friends_location, friends_likes

Comment: @Ash, how would i get friends_hometown from $friends =  $facebook->api("/me/friends");??

Answer (score 0):

What does Facebook respond for your request '/FriendID' ?

Comment: the page keeps on loading..but it doesn't display anything :S

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the answer is what you expect? I'm not sure for the friendId response, but you could use another method such as user information

```
$friendsIds = array(1,2,3);
$requestInfo = array(
'method' => 'users_getInfo',
'friends' => $friendsIds,
'user_info' => array('last_name', 'first_name', 'uid', 'birthday')
)
$userDetails = $facebook->api->($requestInfo);
print_r($userDetails);
```

You can test it or an appropriate code to your schedule, I only explained the idea of how you can get what you want