# Guidelines for Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an android app which requests a significantly large amount of data from facebook graph api. As I see, facebook does not give you all the data if the number of requests through the graph api exceed a certain limit. I have tried batch requests but they are as expensive as a multiple graph api requests. I have also tried fql but I am not getting responses to certain queries in fql.What are some of the guidelines that I should follow in order to make sure that my app functions smoothly and I get all the data that I request?

EDIT

I am collecting all the data using php. I have configured a server to make all these requests.

Comment: You may refer:

[Link1][1]


[Link2][2]


[Link3][3]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645595/how-to-get-all-friends-name-id-birthday-location-etc-from-facebook-api-in
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393610/how-to-get-friends-birthday-list-using-facebook-api
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393446/android-facebook-api-user-info-birthdays-and-events-request

Answer (score 0):

You may refer:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645595/how-to-get-all-friends-name-id-birthday-location-etc-from-facebook-api-in)

[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393610/how-to-get-friends-birthday-list-using-facebook-api)

[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393446/android-facebook-api-user-info-birthdays-and-events-request)

[Link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251664/android-get-birthday-dates-from-facebook-profile/12274830#12274830)

You also should have posted some of your workouts for readers' better understanding and to get a better answer for your question