# How to get friends birthday list from facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get friend's birthday list using facebook api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393610/how-to-get-friends-birthday-list-using-facebook-api)

I'm developing an application and all my users are also facebook user. Now I want to send emails from admin section to that user's friends about his birthday. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to retrieve a user's friend's email address, so you won't be able to do that.

It's trivial to retrieve a user's friend's birthdays provided they've given you the appropriate permissions though. You'll need the `friends_birthday` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) to do this, and once you have that permission the query is just `/me/friends?fields=birthday`

Comment: Yeah i'm getting those info. Please ready my previous comment what I'm trying to do. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: No, i covered that in my answer, you can't retrieve email addresses for friends of the current user (unless those friends have also granted your app the `email` extended permission)

Comment: Sorry I missplaced my comments. Here's it is. I took all necessary permissions.

Yeah I'm getting my friends birthday when I'm logged in. Suppose I want to get your friends birthday with your access token. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you need me to have granted the friends_birthday permission though, then just access `/<MY UID>/friends?fields=birthday` as above

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could send a FQL query to get the birthday, look into User table.
developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

I feel you need to request permission to the user for that.

Comment: Yeah I'm getting my friends birthday when I'm logged in. Suppose I want to get your friends birthday with your access token. Is it possible?

Comment: Only for the friends who are also users of your app, and you have a current access token for that friend.  No other way to get it.