# Unable to fetch user email and birthday using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am writing a program in which i am trying to get `user's basic information` like: `Id`, `Name`, `Email`, `Birthday`, `Locale` and etc.

And i am successfully `fetched` these details: Id, Name, Locale

But `getting null` while fetching: Email & Birthday

check my code below:

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_location", "user_birthday");
    String get_id, get_name, get_gender, get_email, get_birthday, get_locale, get_location;

............................................................

loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {             

            if (user != null) {

                userName.setText("Hello, " + user.getName());

                userInformation.setText(buildUserInfoDisplay(user));
            } else {
                userName.setText("You are not Logged In");
                userInformation.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}

private String buildUserInfoDisplay(GraphUser user) {
    StringBuilder userInfo = new StringBuilder("");
    userInfo.append(String.format("First Name: %s\n\n", user.getFirstName()));
    userInfo.append(String.format("Last Name: %s\n\n", user.getLastName()));
    userInfo.append(String.format("Birthday: %s\n\n", user.getBirthday()));
    userInfo.append(String.format("Email: %s\n\n", user.getProperty("email")));
    userInfo.append(String.format("Locale: %s\n\n", user.getProperty("locale")));
    return userInfo.toString();
}
```

Now what i am `getting`:

**First Name:** `Kim`

**Last Name:** `DSouza`

**Birthday:** `null`

**Email:** `null`

**Locale:** `en_US`

Comment: What request are you making to get all those fields? You need to specifically ask for email and birthday if you want those fields

Comment: +1 try refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251664/android-get-birthday-dates-from-facebook-profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hye all i found the problem, that was very small just use this in your activity:

```
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);

            if (session.isOpened()) {
                 Log.i(TAG,"Access Token"+ session.getAccessToken());
                   Request.newMeRequest(session,
                       new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
              @Override
              public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,Response response) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: This is not working ,Not able to get email with this

Answer (score 0):

You can get email id ,birthday using like

For email:

```
String email = user.getProperty("email").toString();
```

For Birthday:

```
String birth  =user.getBirthday()
```