# Facebook Graph API 2.2 : Returns empty friends list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

With latest graph API 2.2 I have taken all care for calling `me/friends` mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends) api but I am still getting blank list of friends.

I took care, that two of my friends with whom i am already a friend. They logged in to this app via facebook login. I also check the visibility section and ensured it is public. Though the app is always returning me a empty friend list and I'm stuck how to move ahead.

Comment: Check Permissions and Modifiers Part carefully on that article of mentioned link...if problem then persist then share screen shot of coding snippet and output...

Answer (score 1):

If the friend list is empty, there are usually 2 reasons why:

- None of your friends authorized the App (in your case, this shouldn´t be it)
- You didn´t authorize with the `user_friends` permission (every friend needs to authorize with that permission too)

`user_friends` is only approved, but you still need to ask for it in the login process.

Comment: How my friends authorize the app ?, I enabled user_friends, is it possible to get friends birthday.

Comment: how to authorize an app is explained in the docs. if you want to get the birthday of a user, that specific user has to authorize your app with the user_birthday permission. it is very simple: no data from anyone without his explicit permission.

Comment: again, you cannot get birthdays of friends if they did not authorize your app with the user_birthday permission. if they did, then just try /me/friends?fields=name,birthday

Comment: What I understood is my friends also should log in through the same app Id, then will get my friends birthday right? but its complicated, because I just need them birthdays to my app, for that purpose how can I force my friends to use same? It does not make sense.

Comment: you don´t "force" anyone. you just only get data of friends who authorized your app too. that´s really all there is to say about it, not sure what does not make sense.

Comment: Okay, the facebook will authorize my app ?? then can I get my friends birthday ?

Comment: I just confuesed of who want to authorize my app and how?

Comment: how is explained in detail in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: after review my app, users can login and can give permission to access friends, hope I will get friends ID as well but is it possible to get birthday by using friends ID ? This edge allows you to:: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends

Comment: again: you can ONLY get access to friends who authorized your app too. there is no way to access ALL friends, and there is no way to get the birthday of a friend who did not specifically authorize your app with the user_birthday permission. not sure what else to tell you, this should be 100% clear.

Comment: +1 It's clear after reading your post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393610/how-to-get-friends-birthday-list-using-facebook-api/28747657#28747657